# attribute error when trying to create a button on MDDialog

Tags: kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I'm doing a separate class so that, when there are exceptions, a popup will appear with the MDDialog, what I want is that, when clicking on the "OK" button, the popup will disappear. Simple, isn't it? But when I click, this error appears:

```
AttributeError: 'MDRaisedButton' object has no attribute 'my_dialog'
```

This is MDDialogApp.py to create the MDDialog:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRaisedButton
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog


class MDDialogAppTest(MDApp):

    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(MDDialogAppTest, self).__init__()
        self.my_dialog = None

    # Pop up for exceptions
    def show_mddialog(self, msg):
        self.my_dialog = MDDialog(
            title='Oops, an error occurred',
            text=msg,
            type='alert',
            size_hint=[.5, .5],
            auto_dismiss=False,
            buttons=[
                MDRaisedButton(
                    text="OK", on_release=self.dialog_callback
                )
            ],

        )
        self.my_dialog.open()

    def dialog_callback(self):
        self.my_dialog.dismiss()
```

This is my test.py to reproduce the error:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp

from Automation.App import MDDialogApp
from Automation.App.MDDialogApp import MDDialogAppTest

KV = '''
MDFloatLayout:

    MDFlatButton:
        text: "ALERT DIALOG"
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
        on_release: app.click_button()
'''

class Example(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        self.my_dialog = None
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def click_button(self):
        MDDialogApp.MDDialogAppTest.show_mddialog(self=MDDialogAppTest, msg="error: something")

Example().run()
```

I would like to understand what i'm doing wrong here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I cannot duplicate your error. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry @JohnAnderson just edited my question.

Comment: You are calling the `show_mddialog()` method of the `MDDialogAppTest` as though it were a static method, but it is not, it is an instance method. So, when the `OK` button is pressed the `self` value that gets passed to the `dialog_callback()` method is the button instance, causing the error. That is a very odd construct. Are you restricted in some way?  Can you just move your `build()` and `click_button()` methods into the `MDDialogAppTest` so that you can call `show_mddialog()` as simply `self.show_mddialog("error: something")`?

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation, now I understand what was really happening. The goal was to be able to use MDDialogAppTest for different .py files, just as an exception popup for example, to avoid redundancy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way to use methods that are defined in another `App` class is to just extend that `App`. This approach would make your `Example` app change:

```
class Example(MDDialogAppTest):

    def build(self):
        self.my_dialog = None
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def click_button(self):
        self.show_mddialog(msg="error: something")
```

and back in your `MDDialogAppTest` class, you will need to adjust the `dialog_callback()` method to allow additional args:

```
def dialog_callback(self, *args):
    self.my_dialog.dismiss()
```